# 'post' table usability - error when installing .ttf font on mac

Tags: macos, fonts, truetype

So, when i try to install a .ttf font on my mac it stops installing and gives me this message

**1 serious error was found. Do not use this font file.**

and in the list there is, **'post' table usability** , flagged as red

I'm really curious.. 
- what does the error actually wanna tell me?
- what could happen if i use, or perhaps just install it?
- and what does 'post' mean in that list of all things?

Is it a bug, is it serious, or just nonsense!?

Thank you!

Comment: Unless you are actively involved in programming FontBook (in which case we'd like to see a [mcve] of your problematic code), this is a *general* computer related question. Since it's a very specific Mac issue, better ask on [apple.se].

Comment: thank you! @usr2564301 
i didn't knew that this Ask Different thing exists.
no i'm not at all involved in programming FontBook!

Comment: But, to give you a useful comment: it means the font you're trying to install is broken and does not pass validation based on what the OpenType specification says fonts should look like at the byte level. So it could be an incomplete download, a poorly generated font, an intentionally broken font that works in whatever you took it from but won't allow you to install it because you're not allowed to, etc. etc. If this is supposed to be a font that's legal for you to install, try downloading a fresh copy. If it's not... stop trying to install it ;)